# Googlemaps Marker InfoWindow align Images to ParentLeft/Right

Tags: java, android, google-maps, code-snippets

I'm having some problem related to the layout of the infoWindow. I have built my own custom infoWindow with it's own xml file. There are two ImageButtons inside which i want to align to the ParentLeft and ParentRight. Though I don't want the parent to take the maximum width of the screen, like in pic #2.

In pic #1 I tried to align the buttons to the left and right of the snippet title, though the title gets changed dynamically and the images are ontop of the title. I know I can fix that problem programatically right after I changed the snippet title, though that's not the real problem here.

How do I set the images to the outer left and right side of the snippet without taking up the whole width?

[image: One]
[image: Two]

Answer (score 0):

Solution was simple.

I didn't read the specifications on the layout relevant xml attributes correctly, so I misused "android:layout_alignRight" in my code.

In the first picture I aligned the left edge of the blue button with the left edge of the title. The solution was to align the left edge of the blue button with the left edge of the tableLayout below.